# CSRF on a login page

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection

I have a CSRF Token on the login page, which works as expected. So when user has the login page open for a long time (the token has expired in the background). When they enter their login credentials correctly, it tells them that the action is invalid because the token has expired and redirects them to login page again, where they can now successfully enter.

I think the behavior is as expected, because the CSRF token has become stale and an explicit action has fetched the correct token. The users hate it because they need to enter the login information twice.

ANy advice? This seems like a very common problem with CSRF on a login page that sits there for a long time..

Thanks and appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry but, how often do your users have this problem? Do you have other activities on the login page that is distracting them?

Comment: Pretty often. They will let their session time out and get redirected to the login page. After several hours they will try to login and get CSRF error and they get redirected to login again, which gets the new token from server. Then they can login. It is like double login to work..

Comment: Have you considered automatic refreshing set to a time roughly equal to the expiration of a CSRF token?

Answer (score 3):

Given what you specify in the comment, I'd suggest you implement an automatic refresh set to around the same interval as the expiration of your CSRF tokens.

Just throw this into the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

In this example, it will refresh every 5 minutes.